# PHP minimum precision on a number

Tags: php, numbers, rounding

I have a list of numbers coming from a database that range from  0.001 to 10 and I need to display them with a **minimum** precision of 2 decimal places but no maximum precision.

Example numbers and expected conversion:

- 1 -> 1.00
- 0.1 -> 0.10
- 0.01 -> 0.01
- 0.001 -> 0.001
- 1.234 -> 1.234
- 0.035 -> 0.035
- 25.5 -> 25.50

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function min_precision($x, $p)
{
  $e = pow(10,$p);
  return floor($x*$e)==$x*$e?sprintf("%.${p}f",$x):$x;
}

foreach (Array(1,0.1,0.01,0.001,1.234,0.035,25.5) as $x)
{
  echo $x . " -> " . min_precision($x,2) . "\n";
}
```

output:

```
1 -> 1.00
0.1 -> 0.10
0.01 -> 0.01
0.001 -> 0.001
1.234 -> 1.234
0.035 -> 0.035
25.5 -> 25.50
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$number = split('.', $dbNumber);
if(strlen($number[1]) < 2)
     $resultNumber = number_format($dbNumber,2);
else
     $resultNumber = $dbNumber;
```

where $dbNumber is the number coming from the datababase

Comment: `split()` uses a regular expression as its first argument, not a string literal. To make this work, either change it to `explode('.', $dbNumber)` (preferred for PHP 5.3 as `split` is deprecated) or use `split('\.', $dbNumber)`.

Answer (score -2):

`number_format(25.5, 2)`

http://us.php.net/number_format